# Using Powershell to access Static class within a Static Class

Tags: class, powershell, static

I have a class as like the following

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{
    public static class ParentClass
    {
      public const string myValue = "Can get this value";

      public static class ChildClass
      {
        public const string myChildValue = "I want to get this value";
      }
     }
}
```

I can get the myValue using powershell,

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Foo.Bar")
$parentValue = [Foo.Bar.ParentClass]::myValue
```

But I'm unable to get the class within the class myChildValue. Can anyone help?

Thought it might be something like below but $childValue is always empty.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Foo.Bar")
$childValue = [Foo.Bar.ParentClass.ChildClass]::myChildValue
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's `[Foo.Bar.ParentClass+ChildClass]`. On PowerShell 3 tab completion will tell you as much. Furthermore, you can use `Add-Type` to compile and load the code directly:

```
C:\Users\Joey> add-type 'namespace Foo.Bar
>> {
>>     public static class ParentClass
>>     {
>>       public const string myValue = "Can get this value";
>>
>>       public static class ChildClass
>>       {
>>         public const string myChildValue = "I want to get this value";
>>       }
>>      }
>> }'
>>
C:\Users\Joey> [Foo.Bar.ParentClass+ChildClass]::myChildValue
I want to get this value
```

No need to fiddle around with the C# compiler and `[Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName`.

Comment: Thank you, extra point for answering so fast. Is that what + sign for, so if there was a class underneath the childclass would it me Foo.Bar.ParentClass+ChildClass+ChildOfChildClass

Comment: The `+` is from the internal name of that class. C# uses the dot `.` for both namespace separation and nested classes, but .NET itself doesn't. This becomes apparent when you use reflection to access types as well (and is also documented [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w3f99sx1.aspx), about halfway down the page). So yes, nested nested classes would use `+` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the link and explanation.